# BLE Beacon with custom data broadcasting

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

In the application I am looking forward Bluetooth in Beacon is very good option as I want to collect PH from different sources to the application so I can't pair my android device with all the BLE devices at a time as it will be around 20-30.

But I can see that if there is Beacon then Android can scan all of them and also get the RSSI of all devices without being paired with them.

So is it possible that we add few other parameter for example PH, Temperature, Humidity and 3-4 other parameters so Beacon is going to broadcast all these parameter along with RSSI and in Android app I can collect all the information?

- I am not sure if this is feasible solution or not and if it is then how to achieve this in beacon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bluetooth beacons generally rely upon advertisement packets to send data, which are limited in the number of bytes available.  For manufacturer advertisements, you basically have 24 usable bytes to work with, although you need to reserve some of these as a flag to indicate it is your beacon format, and not somebody else's beacon format.

You can look at the [AltBeacon spec](https://github.com/AltBeacon/spec) as an example.  This format uses two bytes to identify itself (the "beacon code"), 20 bytes of beacon identifiers, one byte of data and one byte for reference RSSI.  You probably still want a unique identifier for each beacon so you know which beacon sent you the information.  But you might be able to cut this down to four bytes for your purposes, which would allow you to have 2^32 different beacons sending this information.

The [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) lets you both transmit and receive beacons using arbitrary formats you can define using the [BeaconParser](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/javadoc/index.html) class.  A beacon format that uses a four byte identifier, two bytes each for PH, Temperature and Humidity data fields, and two bytes each for five other data fields might look like this:

```
m:2-3=abcd,i:4-7,d:8-9,d:10-11,d:12-13,d:14-15,d:16-17,d:18-19,d:20-21,d:22-23,p:24-24
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! 
And how we can change ids during work of beacon? Need recreating him every time (after update data)? For example in android phone = for old data beacon - we call stopAdvertising() , and in same time we will create new beacon (with new ids) with calling startAdvertising()?

Comment: Yes, what you say will work.